# Remove numbers with 5 in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my code to return this result:

```
>>>dont_give_five(1,9) #1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 (5 excluded)
8
>>>dont_give_five(4,17) #4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17 (5 and 15 excluded)
12
```

This is the code I have tried and my count is 24 not 8.

```
def dont_give_five(start,end):
    nums = list(range(start,end+1))
    nums = str(nums)
    count = 0
    for i in nums:
        if i != '5':
            count +=1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You convert the list itself to string. Use `map` to convert the individual elements to `str` like this:

```
def dont_give_five(start,end):
    nums = map(str, list(range(start,end+1)))
    count = 0
    for i in nums:
        if '5' not in i:
            count +=1
    return count
```

Hope it helps!